# How to save already displayed image in Dlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, dlib

After run the code

```py
import dlib
from skimage.io import imsave, imread

sp = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
facerec = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat')
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

img = io.imread('foto.jpg')
win1 = dlib.image_window()
win1.clear_overlay()
win1.set_image(img)

dets = detector(img, 1)
for k, d in enumerate(dets):
    print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
        k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
    shape = sp(img, d)
    win1.clear_overlay()
    win1.add_overlay(d)
```

I have got an image with the drawing face landmarks in a separate window.

How do I save the image from the window to a file?

I was tried something like to

```py
imsave('file.jpg',shape)
```

but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Since you tagged OpenCV, you can use [cv2.imwrite](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite) to save the image

Comment: if I wrote cv2.imwrite('filename',shape) I have got error

Comment: What error? Like this `cv2.imwrite('new.jpg', shape)`?

Comment: Error: cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',shape)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'  
       ------------------------------------------                                                                  
        the shape is <class 'dlib.full_object_detection'> and  cv2 cant work with it

Comment: Try `cv2.imwrite('new.jpg', cv2.UMat(shape))`

Comment: TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found